# Как вытащить слово, идущее после "@"?

Tags: c#

Дана строка:

> "caption":"\u041d\u0430\u0448 \u043d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439
>   \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0435\u043a\u0442
>   @failsru\n.\n\ud83d\udc6b\u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u0447\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0435
>   \u0441\u0432\u043e\u0438\u0445
>   \u0434\u0440\u0443\u0437\u0435\u0439\ud83d\udc6b\n.\n@dontjudgerussia\n.\n#\u043f\u043b\u044f\u0436#\

Как получить всё то, что идёт после символа @? т.е failsru и dontjudgerussia

Comment: Изменять вопрос после данного ответа не очень правильно по отношению к отвечающим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для работы со строками используются регулярные выражения.
В вашем случае вполне достаточно искать по следующему шаблону `"@(\\w+)"`.
Чтобы получить искомые слова воспользуйтесь методом Regex.Matches

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "@(\\w+)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var words = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```